# How to keep a varible from passing @{ } instead of just the value

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-5.0

I am attempting to pull OU info from out-gridview instead of having to open AD and re-name a OU to copy it to paste into a get-host var.

When I use the code below, it is passing @{value to be sent}. Even when I tell the var to be $ouname.name it still only places @{value} instead of value. How do I just send the value of the var? Is this a result of using out-grid view instead of just pasting the value I want into a get-host = $ouname?

```
# Use a GUI to provide an OU list to select from.
$OUName = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domainname,DC=local" -Filter '*' | 
Select Name| 
Sort Name | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select the OU name to search' 

#Get ActiveSync and Mailbox data
$EASDevices = ""
$AllEASDevices = @()

$EASDevices = ""| select 'User','PrimarySMTPAddress','DeviceType','DeviceModel','DeviceOS', 'LastSyncAttemptTime','LastSuccessSync'
$EasMailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=$OUname,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domainname,DC=local" -ResultSize unlimited
foreach ($EASUser in $EasMailboxes) {
$EASDevices.user = $EASUser.displayname
$EASDevices.PrimarySMTPAddress = $EASUser.PrimarySMTPAddress.tostring()
    foreach ($EASUserDevices in Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox $EasUser.alias) {
$EASDeviceStatistics = $EASUserDevices | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics
    $EASDevices.devicetype = $EASUserDevices.devicetype
    $EASDevices.devicemodel = $EASUserDevices.devicemodel
    $EASDevices.deviceos = $EASUserDevices.deviceos
$EASDevices.lastsyncattempttime = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsyncattempttime
$EASDevices.lastsuccesssync = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsuccesssync
    $AllEASDevices += $EASDevices | select user,primarysmtpaddress,devicetype,devicemodel,deviceos,lastsyncattempttime,lastsuccesssync
    }
    }
$AllEASDevices = $AllEASDevices | sort user
$AllEASDevices
$AllEASDevices | Export-Csv $fname
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I pass the first Var into another var, and call the second var, it will work as intended.

```
# Use a GUI to provide an OU list to select from.
$OUName = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domainname,DC=local" -Filter '*' | 
Select Name| 
Sort Name | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select the OU name to search' 

$ou = $ouname.name

#Get ActiveSync and Mailbox data
$EASDevices = ""
$AllEASDevices = @()

$EASDevices = ""| select 'User','PrimarySMTPAddress','DeviceType','DeviceModel','DeviceOS', 'LastSyncAttemptTime','LastSuccessSync'
$EasMailboxes = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=$OU,OU=Hosted Exchange Customers,DC=Domainname,DC=local" -ResultSize unlimited
foreach ($EASUser in $EasMailboxes) {
$EASDevices.user = $EASUser.displayname
$EASDevices.PrimarySMTPAddress = $EASUser.PrimarySMTPAddress.tostring()
    foreach ($EASUserDevices in Get-ActiveSyncDevice -Mailbox $EasUser.alias) {
$EASDeviceStatistics = $EASUserDevices | Get-ActiveSyncDeviceStatistics
    $EASDevices.devicetype = $EASUserDevices.devicetype
    $EASDevices.devicemodel = $EASUserDevices.devicemodel
    $EASDevices.deviceos = $EASUserDevices.deviceos
$EASDevices.lastsyncattempttime = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsyncattempttime
$EASDevices.lastsuccesssync = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsuccesssync
    $AllEASDevices += $EASDevices | select user,primarysmtpaddress,devicetype,devicemodel,deviceos,lastsyncattempttime,lastsuccesssync
    }
    }
$AllEASDevices = $AllEASDevices | sort user
$AllEASDevices
$AllEASDevices | Export-Csv $fname
```